# Como configurar a versão do android no react-native app

Tags: react-native

Olá eu sou iniciante em React-Native, gostaria ver um exemplo e onde eu configuro a versão mínima do android. Por exemplo: Queria compilar a versão para rodar no android 8 pelo menos. Grato.

Answer (score 1):

É possível configurar a versão minima do `android` que o seu aplicativo poderá ser executado editando o arquivo build.gradle, localizado em `_pasta_do_app/android/build.gradle`.

Temos que alterar a propriedade `minSdkVersion` que indica qual `API` mínima exigida para rodar o aplicativo.

O arquivo editado ficaria assim:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        minSdkVersion = 26 //API 26 corresponde ao android 8.0
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[Lista das versões com as APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)